# Transforming sentence with "as......as"

Tags: adjectives

So, in Wren and Martin, Excercise 60 a statement was given as "Some boys are at least as good as Karim." which needs to be transformed into comparative and superlative.

The solution is given as,
(comparative) "Karim is not more industrious than some other boys." and
(superlative) "Karim is not the most industrious boy."

However, the superlative statement while not wrong factually feels wrong and the comparative statement also feels extremely unnatural.

So I believe it should instead be,
(comparative) "Karim is more industrious than most other boys."
and (superlative) "Karim is one of the most industrious boys."

Are my transformations wrong?

Comment: No: without using "industrious" the comparative entails "Karim is better than some other boys". The superlative entails "Karim is one of the best boys".

Comment: I think you might have misinterpreted the original sentence.  Yes, it uses Karim as a standard for comparison, but it's also saying that some of the boys are *equal to or better than* Karim.